# Get ASCII string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm just wondering if there is in .Net framework method which returns ASCII chars sequence?  Something like:

```
public static string ascii()
{
    return "abcdefghijklmnuopqrstuvwxyz";
}
```

Comment: You can return a byte array using Ascii encoding and every byte of the array is a char wich you can parse, manipulate, use convert.tochar(value) to get the char, etc.

Comment: demas - nothing to do with your question but have you looked at iron python on .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, you wrote it there. And no, there is nothing in the framework to do so. Why would there be? This method isn't solving a particular problem and it's downright trivial to write yourself. Note though, that the naming convention would dictate the name `Ascii` :-)

Comment: I'm move code from python to c# and python has such function in standard library (string.ascii_lowercase).

Comment: News flash: .NET is not Python.

Comment: An even better name would be `EnglishAlphabet`, since there are 128 ASCII characters and this only returns 26 of them...

Comment: Indeed. It's the Latin alphabet, though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In fact `String` already implements `IEnumerable<Char>`, so your code is already you need. But you can make it more specific by changeing the return type:

```
    public IEnumerable<Char> Ascii
    {
        get
        {
            return "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        }
    }
```

If you really like to make it in a more LINQish way you could also write:

```
    public IEnumerable<Char> Ascii2
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range((int)'a', 26).Select(i => (char)i);
        }
    }
```